# Actionscript: how to attach a line end to moving symbol?

Tags: actionscript

how can I animate a line with one end at fixed position and one end following a moving symbol?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Please take a moment to read through ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  People are quite friendly, and enjoy helping others, but those asking questions need to demonstrate that their question was researched, and effort expended to solve the problem on their own before asking.  Most people don't like to answer questions that sound like someone else's homework, and instead prefer to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Programming offers a myriad of way to solve any problem, and your quandary is no different.  A clear example of what you tried will give others a better understanding of context, what methods you've attempted, and how their answer can best fit for your needs.

Is this what you're looking for?

["News Ticker in AS3"](http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/News-ticker-in-Actionscript-3-41430.html)

If not, please revise your question with the aforementioned guidance. Cheers!